# Find the interval of convergence for $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}\cdot x^{2n+2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I have a power series
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}\cdot x^{2n+2}$$
and I need to find the interval of convergence.  I'm not sure if I did this correctly.

I said the interval of convergence is $[-1, 1]$.  I found the radius of the power series to be one after using the ratio test on the power series which resulted in $|x^2| < 1$ for convergence and $|x^2| > 1$ for divergence.  Then I just tested the end points and found that both -1 and 1 converged.  Is that correct?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Yes, it is correct since you're assuming $x$ to be real. The ratio test can also be used for complex numbers, however, and then the sum would diverge for $x=\pm i$ since that would make $x^2=-1$ and give the harmonic sum which diverges.